# Accompanying my husband on business travel

Tags: usa, international-travel

I am a housewife not working currently but my Husband is going to travel on a Business visa to the US for three weeks from his Office sponsor next Jan. Both i and my baby close to 2 years hold a passport. Just fyi, I also have a Business visa stamped since i travelled two years ago from my organization to the US. But at present I m a stay at home mom though my Business visa is valid for another 5 years. 
Can both me n my son travel with Husband to the US this time? 
What are the additional documents required for me n my son while we accompany my Husband during the three weeks. Other than Marriage certificate?

Comment: Just get an ESTA, but what country is this from??

Comment: What's the specific visa type that you have?  What is your citizenship?

Comment: You need to provide more details. Did you have a B1/B2? Check what your visa category was. Normally they give B1/B2 instead of just B1 or B2.

Comment: @Fattie if Evelyn has a business visa, she is likely not eligible for the VWP.

Comment: @TomasBy you have linked to an unofficial site that charges $88 for something that people can get directly from the official site for $14.  The official site is at https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.